# Move to start and end of search lookup in Emacs

Tags: emacs

How can you have the point at the beginning or end of the search string when accepting a search ?

So say you do C-s "foobar", I would like to have my cursor at the end of the found string when I press RET and at the beginning if I press C-RET.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
(defun my-isearch-exit-other-end ()
  "Exit isearch at the other end"
  (interactive)
  (when isearch-forward (goto-char isearch-other-end))
  (isearch-exit))

(define-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "<C-return>") 'my-isearch-exit-other-end)
```